# How can I detect a character that is located within two spaces in python

Tags: python, string

I want my program to detect the letter "o" but that it is within two spaces

I made this little program but it also counts all the "o" and I just want to detect the "o" that is between the word dulce "o" truco

```
word=("dulce o truco")

for i in word:
  if (i == "o" ):
   print("p v q ")
```

Comment: check: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html

Comment: `if " o " in word: print("p v q ")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
word=input().rstrip()

for j in range(1,len(word)-1):
    if word[j]=="o"  and word[j-1]==" " and word [j+1]==" ":
                        print("whatever you want")
```

Would it work? Let me know. The iteration starts at index 1 and ends the one preceding the last character to prevent *index is out of range* error.

Comment: " detect the letter "o" but that it is within two spaces". Yes, I coded according to the mentioned requirement.

Comment: @DimitriDrivakis, Great! Please consider accepting my answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `split`.

```py
word=("dulce o truco")
for i in word.split(' ')[1:]:  # According to @JohnnyMopp comment
    if (i == 'o'):
        print("p v q")
```

For more info about `split` see https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split

Comment: This will give a false positive on something like `word = "o xxxxx"`

Answer (score 1):

simply you can use this

```
word = "dulce o truco"
if ' o ' in word:
    print("whatever you want")
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd just use count which works with substrings as well as single characters.There is a corner case I'm not sure how you'd want to handle " o o " is that one o or two? ie can a space be shared by two of the o values you want to count? If that's the case this won't work.

```
for i in range(word.count(' o ')):
    print("p v q")
```

This would work:

```
for i in range(1,len(word)-1):
    if word[i-1:i+2] == ' o ':
        print("p v q")
```